# TWA "please install chrome dev/canary"

Tags: angular, google-play, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I tried to convert my Angular responsive web app to an Android app (PWA).
To do this I followed this tutorials:

- https://medium.com/poka-techblog/turn-your-angular-app-into-a-pwa-in-4-easy-steps-543510a9b626
- https://css-tricks.com/how-to-get-a-progressive-web-app-into-the-google-play-store/

When I launch the app the following message appears:

> please install chrome dev/canary

After installing chrome dev, it works but I would like to run it as a native app without chrome dev.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions on the article mentioned in the question are **outdated**, and using a **deprecated** support library.

`'com.github.GoogleChrome:custom-tabs-client'` has been deprecated and replaced by an official library maintained by Chrome, `com.google.androidbrowserhelper:androidbrowserhelper`.

You can find updated instructions on the official docs:

- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/integration-guide/

An even easier path is to use a tool that automates building the Android package from the PWA. The tools below are all based on [Bubblewrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bubblewrap/core), which is maintained by the Chrome team to automate packaging a PWA as an Android app:

- Bubblewrap CLI: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bubblewrap/cli
- PWA Builder: https://pwabuilder.com/
- PWA-to-APK: https://appmaker.xyz/pwa-to-apk/

Comment: Ops forgot to remove my post as I found a solution before seeing your by using `pwabuilder.com`. I'll accept your answer for future readers as it's well explained !